# How to calculate walking/cycling/Driving distance between two Longitudes and Latitudes

Tags: google-bigquery, distance, haversine

I am working on a grocery delivery app, where grocery stores are spread across the city. I have coordinates info of all the grocery stores, and I also have coordinates for address where the items need to be delivered. Now I need to find shortest WALKING/CYCLING/DRIVING distance between grocery store and the address.

For example, below if the info about Stores
Lati.   Longi.
Store1  5.2312  23.1223
Store2  7.2356  30.1235

```
                Lati.   Longi.
```

Delivery Address    4.2356  15.2312

Output should look like:

```
                Lati.   Longi.     Store1           Store2
```

Delivery Address    4.2356  15.2312    2 KM Walking         1 KM walking
2.3 KM CYCLING   1.2 KM CYCLING
4 KM DRIVING         1.5 KM DRIVING

I am using ST_DISTANCE() from Big query to compute the distance.

st_distance(
st_geogpoint(23.1223, 5.2312),--Store1 coordinates
st_geogpoint(15.2312, 4.2356),--Delivery address coordinates
)/1000) as dist_from_Store1_KM,

(   st_distance(
st_geogpoint(30.1253, 7.2356), --Store2 coordinates
st_geogpoint(15.2312, 4.2356), --Delivery Address coordinates
)/1000) as dist_from_Store2_KM,

But I am not sure if the output is WALKING distance or SHORTEST distance between two points?

I am kind of stuck and not sure if there is any other way to compute the distance without using any APIs?

Answer (score 0):

ST_DISTANCE is straight-line distance ("as crow flies"). It does not know anything about or takes into account available roads.

To compute walking distance, you need to obtain and take into account actual map data.

One way to do it is to call external service, like Google Maps:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/overview

Another way is to use free data sets, e.g. Open Streets Maps data, which is available as public dataset in BigQuery, and build path using it. Carto built such functionality it as part of its Analytic Toolbox, see their blog for excellent details:
https://carto.com/blog/how-to-do-route-optimization-at-scale-with-carto-bigquery